# ssrs matrix seperated by commas and according to Gender

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

hello i have question in ssrs  Matrix.

I have created Name,Gender,Year of born table and i want to display in names separated by commas and according to gender
in the name i have used following matrix

```
------------------------------
-----------------------------
Gender           ||   [Year]
------------------------------
------------------------------
------------------------------
[Gender]         || [Expr]
-------------------------------
-------------------------------
-----------------------------------
---------------------------
```

`Expr =Join(Lookupset(true,Fields!BornYear.Value,Fields!BornYear.Value & " " & Fields!Gender.Value,Fields!Name.Value,"DataSet1"),","` ...but it is displaying all the names of all gender.
so how to shuffle names according to gender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your expression is working - there are too many arguments in the lookupset.

I think your issue is using the TRUE - you're comparing TRUE to the year which will always be TRUE. ( (TRUE = 5) = true ).

You want to combine the Year and Gender and compare them to get your list like:

```
=Join(Lookupset(Fields!BornYear.Value & "|" & Fields!Gender.Value, Fields!BornYear.Value & "|" & Fields!Gender.Value, Fields!Name.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")
```

Comment: Hi Fist,
Thanks for your answer . .I'm new to ssrs

=Join(Lookupset(Fields!BornYear.Value & "|" & Fields!Gender.Value, Fields!BornYear.Value & "|" & Fields!Gender.Value, Fields!Name.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")

this is what i want but i used above as
=Join(Lookupset(Fields!BornYear.Value & Fields!Gender.Value, Fields!BornYear.Value &  Fields!Gender.Value, Fields!Name.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ").... What is the Difference between & and & "|" & ?

Comment: I usually use the pipe "|" to separate fields when combining them into one string. You probably don't need it in your instance but it's helpful when you have data that can be misconstrued - i.e. `"20" & "12" = "201" & "2"` but `"20" & "|" & "12" <> "201" & "|" & "2"` .

Comment: Ok Thanks for the comment. I will use Pipe"|" from now on